# Why does an operation on a large integer silently overflow?

Tags: python, pandas, long-integer

I have a list that contains very large integers and I want to cast it into a pandas column with a specific dtype. As an example, if the list contains `2**31`, which is outside the limit of int32 dtype, casting it into dtype int32 throws an Overflow Error, which lets me know to use another dtype or handle the number in some other way beforehand.

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.Series([2**31], dtype='int32')

# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

But if a number is large but inside the dtype limits (i.e. `2**31-1`), and some number is added to it which results in a value that is outside the dtype limits, then instead of an OverflowError, the operation is executed without any errors, yet the value is now inverted, becoming a completely wrong number for the column.

```py
pd.Series([2**31-1], dtype='int32') + 1

0   -2147483648
dtype: int32
```

Why is it happening? Why doesn’t it raise an error like the first case?

PS. I'm using pandas 2.1.1 and numpy 1.26.0 on Python 3.12.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Why does an operation on a large integer silently overflow?*

As a short answer, that's because of how [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) deals with [*overflows*](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors).

---

On my platform (with the same versions of Python/Packages as yours) :

```
from platform import *
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd

system(), version(), machine()
python_version(), pd.__version__, np.__version__

('Linux',
 '#34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2',
 'x86_64')
('3.12.0', '2.1.1', '1.26.0')
```

I can reproduce your issue but with a larger integer than the one you choose as an example :

`pd.Series([2**63], dtype="int32")` raises this :

> `OverflowError`: Python int too large to convert to C long

While `pd.Series([2**31], dtype="int32")` raises this :

> `ValueError`: Values are too large to be losslessly converted to `int32`. To cast anyway, use `pd.Series(values).astype(int32)`

#### Details

Let's agree that you're using two different type of objects, which potentially means two different scenarios, *i.e, 1) error raised or 2) no error raised* :

1. [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) : the Series constructor
2. [`pd.Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) : a method of the former

##### The construction : `pd.Series([2**31], dtype="int32")`

It is handled behind the scenes by [`sanitize_array`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.1/pandas/core/construction.py#L518) which receives your input (*the list* `[2**31]`, *i.e* `[2147483648]`) and call in this case [`maybe_cast_to_integer_array`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.1/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py#L1569). The latter will make a classical NumPy construction using [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) :

```
casted = np.array([2147483648], dtype="int32")
```

> `DeprecationWarning`: NumPy will stop allowing conversion of out-of-bound Python integers to integer arrays.  The conversion of `2147483648` to `int32` will fail in the future.
> For the old behavior, usually:
> `np.array(value).astype(dtype)`
> will give the desired result (**the cast overflows**).
> `np.array([2147483648], dtype='int32')`

You may ask yourself why the warning above doesn't show off while constructing your Series, well that's because pandas [**silents**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.1/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py#L1614) it. Now, right after casting, pandas calls [`np.asarray`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.1/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py#L1647) without specifying a dtype to let NumPy infer a dtype (*which is* `int64` *here*) : `arr = np.asarray(arr)`. And since, `casted.dtype < arr.dtype`, the `ValueError` is triggered.

##### The addition : `pd.Series([2**31-1], dtype="int32") + 1`

This one is delegated to [`_na_arithmetic_op`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.1/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py#L191) that receives `array([2147483647], dtype=int32)` and `1` and try to add them together with the help of [`_evaluate_standard`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py#L67) to make a classical [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.add) operation that is equivalent to `np.array([2147483647]) + 1` and since [**the fixed size of NumPy numeric types may cause overflow errors when a value requires more memory than available in the data type**](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors), the result is the `array([-2147483648], dtype=int32)` which is passed to [`sanitize_array`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.1/pandas/core/construction.py#L518) to construct back a Series :

```
pd.Series([2**31-1], dtype="int32") + 1

0   -2147483648
dtype: int32
```

NB : When you go beyond the limit of the `int32`, NumPy wraps around to the minimum value :

```
a = np.array([2**31-1], dtype="int32"); b = 1
a+b # this gives array([-2147483648], dtype=int32)
```

Here is some other examples :

```
def wrap_int32(i, N, l=2**31):
    return ((i+N) % l) - l

wrap_int32(2**31, 0) # -2147483648
wrap_int32(2**31, 1) # -2147483647
wrap_int32(2**31, 2) # -2147483646
wrap_int32(2**31, 3) # -2147483645
# ...
```

---

> *I have a list that contains very large integers and I want to cast it into a pandas column with a specific dtype. As an example, if the list contains `2**31`, which is outside the limit of `int32` dtype, casting it into dtype `int32` throws an `OverflowError`, **which lets me know to use another dtype or handle the number in some other way beforehand**.*

Maybe you should consider opening an [*issue*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug%2CNeeds+Triage&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml&title=BUG%3A+) so that the arithmetic operations made by pandas raise an error in case of an overflow. And as a workaround (*or maybe a solution?*) for your usecase, you can try catching upstream the integers that doesn't fall within the `int32` range :

```
iint32 = np.iinfo(np.int32)

lst = [100, 1234567890000, -1e19, 2**31, 2**31-1, -350]

out = [i for i in lst if iint32.min <= i and i <= iint32.max]
# [100, 2147483647, -350]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure, but as an educated guess:

The first overflow happens on the border between Python and C, and the overflow is being detected during the conversion. However, the second overflow is happening entirely within C, where no integer overflow checks exist.

Answer (score 2):

Let's find out:

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([2**31-1], dtype='int32')
type(s[0])
type((pd.Series([2**31-1], dtype='int32') + 1)[0])
type(s[0] + 1)
pd.Series([1,2,3], dtype='int32') + 1
```

```
<class 'numpy.int32'>
<class 'numpy.int32'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
0    2
1    3
2    4
dtype: int32
```

Pandas performs the addition operation on a `Series` and enforces type. Numpy takes over while accessing an element of the `Series` (type: `numpy.int32`) and performing addition. Numpy coerces the type to `numpy.int64` in order to avoid overflow.

Comment: Python 3.10.3, pandas 2.1.1, numpy 1.26.0

Comment: It's probably a platform-dependent thing, which would be a consequence of @Amadan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python's int is actually some sort of Bignum type. You are explicitly trying to convert a python's int of [unlimited precision](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) to a 32-bit int (C-long), and therefore the conversion itself raises the exception in such scenario.

In fact, even in numpy, if you the input number is beyond the boundary of np.uint64, the same error would occur.

###### Scenario 1 - overflow (deprecated in 1.25.2 - will fail in future)

```
np.asarray([2**31], 'int32')
<input>:1: DeprecationWarning: NumPy will stop allowing conversion of out-of-bound Python integers to integer arrays.  The conversion of 2147483648 to int32 will fail in the future.
For the old behavior, usually:
    np.array(value).astype(dtype)
will give the desired result (the cast overflows).
```

###### Scanario 2 - Overflow error (number greater than uint64 can handle)

```
np.asarray([2**64], dtype='int32')

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Therefore it's really about how the library you use handle these issue when you typecast a Bignum into C-long.

Comment: Well the OverflowError is indeed controlled by implementation of numpy and pandas. Regarding to the second question, once the numbers are already in pandas, the reason is when you create a `pd.Series([2**31 -1, dtype='int32')` first, the pandas successfully convert the 2**31-1 from Python's built-in BigInt to a 32-bit C-long. And then when you add another 1 to this C-long, it's but the overflow of C-long arithmetics.

Comment: The overflow errors you encounter and in my example, occurs when numpy or pandas attempt to convert the python's bigint to C-long, and if the value even exceeds the numpy's uint64 the conversion itself will fail, per numpy/panda's implementation (and raise an OverflowError).

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, Python issues an OverflowError while attempting to build a Series using an integer that exceeds the bounds of int32. This is due to Python detecting the overflow during the process (forming the Series), and it is a simple overflow case.

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    pd.Series([2**31], dtype='int32')
except OverflowError as e:
    print("Overflow Error:", e)
```

in your second example this behavior is typical of how integer overflow is handled at the lowest level in languages like C. It's critical to be aware of this behavior, particularly when working with big numbers.

You may need to include your own checks and error handling in your code if you wish to handle overflow situations in a certain way (by reporting an error).

But you can use the pandas.to_numeric() function to convert the column to a numeric dtype that can handle large integers.

```
import pandas as pd

integer_list = [2**31, 2**31 - 1]

series_int = pd.to_numeric(pd.Series(integer_list), downcast='integer')

print(series_int)
```

[image]

but when I use `[2**3, 2**31 - 1]`

**dtype: int32**

[image]

and `[2**3, 2**3 - 1]`
**dtype: int8**